# Result formula from excel and javascript is different

Tags: javascript, excel

I have excel formula for total penumpang

```
=SUM(D1:D2)-SUM(A3:C3)+C4 and have result 29 when i tried input specific value
```

then i tried javascript

```
 document.getElementById('totalpnp4').value = parseInt(d1)+parseInt(d2)-parseInt(a3)+parseInt(b3)+parseInt(c3)+parseInt(C4); and have result 34 when i tried input same value at excel
```

Then , how to make javascript have same result value as excel function ? Thank you

Comment: can you let me know what the value for D1, D2, A3, C3, C4 ?

Comment: nvm, i realized mistakes . Its same as Triby . Thank you for help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parenthesis to group values:

```
document.getElementById('totalpnp4').value = (parseInt(d1)+parseInt(d2))-(parseInt(a3)+parseInt(b3)+parseInt(c3))+parseInt(C4);
```

Sum a3+b3+c3 before subtract it from previous sum.

Comment: you are right. Now my formula in javascript have same value as excel :)
Thank you